# Dual booting to Ubuntu: No root file system is defined

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, system-installation

I am stuck trying to dual boot to Ubuntu on my Windows computer. I am following exact instructions as described in https://medium.com/@mugglestudies/dual-booting-ubuntu-linux-with-windows-the-official-muggle-studies-guide-f2123c17c3a7

While installing, I am struck at "Installation type" window --5th figure in the link. For comparison, my window comes out without any listing as shown in the image below.

[image]

When I click 'Install Now', it fails and I am getting the following message:
"No root file system is defined. Please correct from the partition menu."

So, it has to do with partitioning the drive. I exactly followed partition creation as suggested in the included link.

On window side, the disk partitions and other relevant properties are shown in the following image:
[image: Disk partition in Window 10]

The parititoned-drive (approx. 220GB) is not encrypted and the format is "ext4", which should be compatible to Linux. Unfortunately, not so.

I have been struggling for more than a day on this. Any suggestions/guidance would be appreciated.

UPDATE
@hoatzin , As you suggested, I ran the live version of Ubuntu and then ran genome-disk. I can see two drives. 128 GB drive is my bootable USB. I do not know what 2.1 GB Loop drive is. I am attaching the screen shot:
[image: Genome-disks]

UPDATE 2:
I believe that my issue is arising from drives on my laptop being in raid-0 configuration. I do not know any solution.

Comment: Check from the Windows side that the disk partitions are simple, not dynamic.  Dynamic partitions do not work with Ubuntu.

Comment: How should I check that? Once I shrank the volume and got an unallocated partition, I ran "simple" dialgo box and also assigned latter "D" to it. The paritition does not seem to be dynamic. But, I may be wrong.

Comment: The Windows tool that displays partitions will have a column for the type, either simple or dynamic.  The ubuntu partition display is totally missing all partitions, so I'd guess being dynamic might be the reason.  They can be converted back to simple, but instructions for that I cannot give.

Comment: I checked. The layout is "Basic", the type is "Simple". So, that is not the issue. The file system is "exFat (Bitlocker encrypted)". So, I am guessing that encryption may be the issue.

Comment: I removed the encryption. Still the same issue/

Comment: I would open the live version of ubuntu (instead of choosing the installation) and run Gnome-disks (Disks).  I am curious if the Disks app would show any disk/partition information there.  If you would do that and share the results it may be helpful.

Comment: @hoatzin , As you suggested, I ran the live version of Ubuntu and then ran genome-disk. I can see two drives. 128 GB drive is my bootable USB. I do not know what 2.1 GB Loop drive is. I am attaching the screen shot in the original post. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: search this site for ahci -- You get the ahci drivers for Windows, Change from raid to ahci in your BIOS/UEFI settings, and then install.  I've never done this, so don't really know the procedure to convert, if any.